# How to handle Google API access_token expired without using google-api-nodejs-client?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I've implemented the code to get access_token, refresh_token and expire_date.
All these values are stored in the database already.

Now I need a way to get another access_token in case the old one is expired without using google-api-nodejs-client package

The reason is this module recently has bug, you can check it here (my comment is the latest)
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/869#issuecomment-352401977
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/894.

At the moment, I tried something like this

```
GoogleTokens.findOne({isObsolete: false}).then((token) => {
                let subscriptionsGetUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/" + req.query.packageName + "/purchases/subscriptions/" + req.query.subscriptionId + "/tokens/" + req.query.token + "?access_token=" + token.accessToken;

                request(subscriptionsGetUrl, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }

                    res.success(JSON.parse(body).expiryTimeMillis);
                });
            });
```

But it will fail when access_token is expired.

Thanks.

Comment: You are required to retrieve new access token using no google-api-nodejs-client. If you have a refresh token, you can retrieve the new access token using the refresh token by POST request. You want to need such method. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike: Hi, I mean I need to detect when the access_token is expired, at that time, I can use the refresh_token to request a new one. The problem is, in the official document, there is nowhere I can find how to detect if access_token is expired.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I posted an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer? You can retrieve the expiration time for access token using OAuth2 API. When you want to retrieve it without google-api-nodejs-client, you can use the following method.

### Sample script :

```
var uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=" + accesstoken;
request.get({uri: uri}, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(body)
});
```

### Response :

#### If the access token can be used yet, the following response is returned.

```
{
    "azp": "#####",
    "aud": "#####",
    "sub": "#####",
    "scope": "#####",
    "exp": "1234567890", // Expiration time
    "expires_in": "3600", // Remaining time
    "access_type": "offline"
}
```

#### If the access token has already not been able to used, the following response is returned.

```
{
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

### Reference :

I got above method from following documents.

- [Validating an ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken)
- [Calling the tokeninfo endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint)
- [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. After some research about this, I used this way: Whenever a 401 Unauthorized appears, I catch it and in the catch, use refresh_token to request a new access_token, and call the API again with access_token

Comment: @Hoang Trinh Thank you for your additional information.

Comment: @Tanaike What about refreshing `idToken`? Please see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975071/google-idtoken-refresh)