# Google idToken Refresh

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using Node `google-auth-library` package to verify idToken at my API server according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth):

```
await googlelib.verifyIdToken(
                {
                    idToken: myToken,
                    audience: myGoogleClientID, 
                }, 
                (e, pass) => {...}
```

Because `idToken` expires in one hour, will be cumbersome to have users log in hourly. I've searched the documents, class `OAuth2Client` has `refreshAccessToken()` no `refreshIdToken()`. How to refresh an expired idToken()?

Note, the only Google APIs I'm using is the Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you require offline access. You can use the one-time code to exchange it for a refresh token that can be used anytime.

```js
$('#signinButton').click(function() {
   auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(signInCallback);
 });
```

In the response, you will have a JSON object with an authorization code:

```json
{"code":"4/yU4cQZTMnnMtetyFcIWNItG32eKxxxgXXX-Z4yyJJJo.4qHskT-UtugceFc0ZRONyF4z7U4UmAI"}
```

This one-time should be done in the back-end and you should persist the refresh token.

You should use [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#readme) to complete this workflow in the back-end. For this,
you'll use the authentication code to get a refresh token. However, as this is an offline workflow,
you also need to verify the integrity of the provided code as the [documentation explains](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth):

```js
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

/**
* Create a new OAuth2Client, and go through the OAuth2 content
* workflow. Return the refresh token.
*/
function getRefreshToken(code, scope) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create an oAuth client to authorize the API call. Secrets should be 
    // downloaded from the Google Developers Console.
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
      YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
      YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
      YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
    );

    // Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
    await oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope,
    });
    
    // Verify the integrity of the idToken through the authentication 
    // code and use the user information contained in the token
    const { tokens } = await client.getToken(code);
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: tokens.id_token!,
      audience: keys.web.client_secret,
    });
    idInfo = ticket.getPayload();
    return tokens.refresh_token;
  })
}
```

With this refresh token, you can create a Google API's client with the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#readme) library anytime.

Take a look at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/flandrade/a943a47e3575fb8805499e18e6b23c07) to review the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My understanding of _offline_ is when internet is unavailable, am I right? But no hurt to look into it. Where is the `one time code` I can find?

Comment: Offline access means that you can use google services on behalf of a user when the user is offline. I edited my answer to add the front-end code. You can also take a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/flandrade/a943a47e3575fb8805499e18e6b23c07

Comment: Very good details and information, definitely another option for me! Thank you and appreciate it again!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, believe the solution is simply manage our [own session](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#create-an-account-or-session).